# Google Cloud Data Fusion subnets issue

Tags: subnet, vpc, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm studing GCP Data Fusion, and after reading the [overwiew] [1](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/concepts/overview) of the service
I tryed to create a first Data Fusion using the [tutorial] [2](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/targeting-campaign-pipeline).

The creation of the pipeline gone well, but on the run statement I got an error about the VPC:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Network 'default' in project '*********' does not contain any subnets. Please create a subnet or use a different network.
```

I checked the documentation where I found  that Data Fusion requires that in the VPC the rule ** default-allow-ssh ** is enabled.
I'm using the default project VPC and in that VPC that rule is enable.

How can I resolve my issue?

Thanks

Stefano G.

---

### Step 2

Hi, to avoid the issue I've created ad new VPC and there I set a subnet where i set the configuration required:

---

ip address range: 10.128.0.0/9

---

firewall rule

**Name**: sg-allow-internal

**Type**: Targets

**Ingress**: "Apply to all"

**IP ranges**: 10.128.0.0/9

**Protocols/ports**:

- tcp:0-65535
- udp:0-65535
- icmp

and now the error is
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter network must conform to the pattern [a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?|[1-9][0-9]{0,19}`

Why?

Answer (score 0):

A GCP VPC can't be used in any region unless it has one or more subnets. Please follow the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc#add-subnets to create a subnet for the default VPC.

Comment: Hi @https://stackoverflow.com/users/13091704/venudhar-ravishankar
My VPC has a subnet

VPC: sgdatafusion  1 Custom 2 Off  
     subnet: us-west1      datafusionsn 10.128.0.0/9 10.128.0.1   Off

Answer (score 0):

The error is talking about the name of the network/subnetwork. You've included the details to your firewall rule which is not the cause of the error. Can you confirm if the name of your network matches that regex?

Comment: But this [a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9] 
means that for the name of the network I can use only letters and numbers, not _ not -, right?